# Problemas ao fazer um get em uma Viewmodel com valores decimais usando o Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Ao efetuar um Get usando o Ajax, a viewModel está chegando na Controller com os campos zerados. Estou criando a classe manualmente, convertendo-a e fazendo o GET. Não consigo descobrir o motivo do problema, se eu estou "setando" os campos com valores em formato errado ou se está acontecendo algum problema ao fazer o stringfy. Já tentei de várias maneiras e não consegui resolver. Alguém saberia como me ajudar?

Obrigado e um abraço a todos!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ViewModel:

```
public class FinanceiroParcelaMovimentoCalculosPadraoViewModel
{
    public decimal ValorASerPago { get; set; }

    public decimal ValorPago { get; set; }

    public decimal PercentualJuros { get; set; }

    public decimal PercentualMulta { get; set; }

    public decimal PercentualDesconto { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("financeiro-parcela-movimento-gerenciar/financeiro-parcela-movimento-calcular-valores-padrao")]
public JsonResult CalcularValoresPadrao(FinanceiroParcelaMovimentoCalculosPadraoViewModel financeiroParcelaMovimentoCalculosPadraoViewModel)
{
    
    return Json(new { financeiroParcelaMovimentoCalculosPadraoViewModel = financeiroParcelaMovimentoCalculosPadraoViewModel });
}
```

JS:

```
var valorASerPago = $("#txt-financeiro-parcela-movimento-valor-a-ser-pago").val();
var valorpago = $("#txt-financeiro-parcela-movimento-valor-pago").val();

var financeiroParcelaMovimentoCalculosPadraoViewModel = {
    ValorASerPago: valorASerPago ? parseFloat(valorASerPago.replace(',', '.')) : 0,
    ValorPago: 0,
    PercentualJuros: 0,
    PercentualMulta: 0,
    PercentualDesconto: 0,

};

$.ajax({
    url: "/financeiro-parcela-movimento-gerenciar/financeiro-parcela-movimento-calcular-valores-padrao",
    type: "GET",
    data: JSON.stringify(financeiroParcelaMovimentoCalculosPadraoViewModel),
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {

       

    },
    error: function () {
        stopLoadGlobal();
        alert("Oops! Algo deu errado.");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, acredito que o ideal e você fazer um post, por segurança da aplicação, se você tem um formulário na tela, basta fazer assim:
serialize: se os campos do formulário for o mesmo da viewModel, ele vai ser reconhecido.

```
function financeiroParcelaMovimento(idRecebido, controller) {

    console.log(idRecebido);
    e.preventDefault();


    var urlCompleto = "/" + controller + "/Adicionar/";
    var t = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
    var formulario = $("#Formulario");

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        headers:
        {
            "RequestVerificationToken": t
        },
        url: urlCompleto,
        data: formulario.serialize(),
        success: function (resultado) {
              console.log(resultado);

        }
    });

}
```